# Удаление элемента рекурсивно (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, рекурсия

У меня есть массив вложенных объектов. Я пытаюсь из него удалить нужный мне элемент. Если я передаю элемент, который не вложен, то все ок. Но если пытаюсь удалить вложенный, то не работает. Подскажите, где ошибка

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

let array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'text 1',
    children: [
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'text 5',
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'text 6',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'text 2',
    children: [],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'text 3',
    children: [
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'text 7',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'text 4',
    children: [],
  },
];

export const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(array);

  const onDelete = (arr, id) => {
    let result = [...arr].filter((item) => {
      if (item.id !== id) {
        return item;
      } else {
        item.children.length && onDelete(item.children, id);
      }
    });
    setState(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onDelete(state, 5);
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Для рекурсивного удаления элементов необходимо использовать рекурсию.

Для этого необходимо написать функцию, которая проверяет один элемент данных и повторить эту функцию для каждого повторяющегося элемента

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} element
 * @property {number} id
 * @property {string} title
 * @property {element[]} children
 * */
/** @type {element[]} */
let array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'text 1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 5,
                title: 'text 5',
                children: [],
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                title: 'text 6',
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'text 2',
        children: [],
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        title: 'text 2',
        children: [
            {
                id: 12,
                title: 'text 2',
                children: [],
            },
            {
                id: 13,
                title: 'text 2',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        title: 'text 2',
                        children: [],
                    },
                    {
                        id: 14,
                        title: 'text 2',
                        children: [
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                title: 'text 2',
                                children: [],
                            },
                            {
                                id: 5,
                                title: 'text 2',
                                children: [],
                            },
                            {
                                id: 17,
                                title: 'text 2',
                                children: [],
                            },],
                    },],
            },],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'text 3',
        children: [
            {
                id: 7,
                title: 'text 7',
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'text 4',
        children: [],
    },
];

/**
 *
 * @param {element[]} arr
 * @param {number} id
 * @return {element[]}
 */
function onDelete(arr, id) {
    const x = arr.filter((item) => {
        if (item.id !== id && item.children.length) {
            return onDelete(item.children, id);
        }
        return item.id !== id;
    });
    x.map((item) => {
        item.children = onDelete(item.children, id);
        return item;
    })

    return x;
}

console.log(1, onDelete(array, 5));
```